# Mask and Filter dsPic30F4011

Tags: c, embedded, can-bus, dspic

I'm programming a dsPIC30F4011 for CAN. But I have problems with specifying the identifier, the mask and the filter.

I use the Standard identifier and the extendet identifier. In bit 16-23 I'll write the adress of the tranceiver.
so, it looks like
00000 00000001 0000000000000001
the spaces are just to show the tranceiver part
I set following bits:

```
// PRIO
C1TX0SIDbits.SID10_6 = 0x0000; 
// SCR
C1TX0SIDbits.SID5_0 = 0x0000;   
C1TX0EIDbits.EID17 = 0x0000;
C1TX0EIDbits.EID16 = 0x0001;
// DEST
C1TX0EIDbits.EID15 = 0x0000;    
C1TX0EIDbits.EID14 = 0x0000;
C1TX0EIDbits.EID13 = 0x0000;
C1TX0EIDbits.EID12 = 0x0000;
C1TX0EIDbits.EID11 = 0x0000;
C1TX0EIDbits.EID10 = 0x0000;
C1TX0EIDbits.EID9 = 0x0000;
C1TX0EIDbits.EID8 = 0x0000;
// CMD
C1TX0DLCbits.EID5_0 = 0x0001;
```

now I have problems with the mask and the filter
I set them

```
// Mask
C1RXM0SID = 0x00FD;
C1RXM0EIDH = 0x0C00;
C1RXM0EIDL = 0x0000;
// Filter
C1RXF0SID = 0x0000;
C1RXF0EIDH = 0x0400;
C1RXF0EIDL = 0x0000;
```

Now I don't receive anythin. If I set

```
C1RXM0SID = 0x000FC;
```

I receive all messages.
I tried it with the transceiver-adress

```
0b00000000
```

and

```
0b00000001
```

So, did I do anything wrong? (I think so, but I don't know what)

Answer (score 0):

> now I have problems with the mask and the filter I set them
>
> ```
> // Mask
> C1RXM0SID = 0x00FD;
> C1RXM0EIDH = 0x0C00;
> C1RXM0EIDL = 0x0000;
> // Filter
> C1RXF0SID = 0x0000;
> C1RXF0EIDH = 0x0400;
> C1RXF0EIDL = 0x0000;
> ```
>
> Now I don't receive anythin. If I set
>
> ```
> C1RXM0SID = 0x000FC;
> ```

This is because you are setting bit 0 of C1RXM0SID. According to the register description in the [reference manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70046E.pdf) this will match only message types (standard or extended address) as determined by EXIDE bit in filter. Bit 1 of this register is unimplemented. Assuming that the SID mask you want is 0xFD then what you want for this register is

```
C1RXM0SID = 0x00FD << 2;
```